# Is it possible to programmatically embed Reddit posts in a page?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, web, embed, reddit

Reddit now offers the possibility to [embed reddit posts and comments](http://mashable.com/2016/05/20/reddit-post-embeds/#Eo0ql1fayZqW) on your page. For posts, the way to do it manually is to click the "share" button, then select "embed" in the pop-up window. This creates a snippet that you can include in your page. However I would like to this automatically with posts I get and select from the reddit API.

Is there an API to generate the snippet? Should I just figure out the format and generate it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[If you check out what the API returns for a subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/popular.json), you'll see that there isn't any data for sharing or embedding unfortunately. Same goes for a [single post](https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/comments/61svww/jared_kushner_had_undisclosed_meeting_with_sergey.json).

If you look at the code for embedding, it's pretty easy to craft yourself.

```
<blockquote class="reddit-card" data-card-created="1490648549"><a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/comments/61svww/jared_kushner_had_undisclosed_meeting_with_sergey/?ref=share&ref_source=embed">Jared Kushner had undisclosed meeting with Sergey Gorkov, the head of Russia’s state-owned Vnesheconombank, which has been under sanctions since the annexation of Crimea in 2014</a> from <a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews">worldnews</a></blockquote>
<script async src="//embed.redditmedia.com/widgets/platform.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

You basically need the current timestamp, the url, the title, and the subreddit. All the data is easily retrievable from the existing API. The second link I posted above should have all the information you need to craft that embed code.

Answer (score 0):

Yh. You can even use IFTTT.COM. Remove the data card created part and replace url with {{PostURL}} and Title work {{title}}. Hope it helps.